# Spritesheet Usage

Tags: java, rpg, spritesheet, processing

I am working on an RPG game and I am storing most of my textures in separate .png files, but for my sprites I would like to use a sprite sheet. How do you cut and store the sheet into individual pictures inside of the program?

I am using Java and the Processing Window.

Comment: Are you asking about how to build a sprite sheet editor where the user positions sprites together into the atlas? Or about how to build a texture packer that automatically generates one texture out of multiple source files? Or about how you can create a spritesheet in advance (possibly in an external tool), and load the pre-made spritesheet in your game?

Comment: @DMGregory, I am preloading the spritesheet.

Comment: You do not need to delete and re-post old comments. This isn't a chat room, and I am not here to reply to you individually. I asked those questions above to prompt you to add more information to your post, to clarify your situation and attract useful answers. What you do with that now is up to you.